# How to reset iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode9.4-beta

How to reset iOS simulator?

[image]

There is no option (sub menu) is Simulator (Menu) with Xcode 9.4 (beta 2), that was in earlier simulators.

[image]

Where can I find it, in Simulator menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is under "Hardware" section.

Answer (score 5):

That option was moved to the "Hardware" menu.

You can also do this from the command line by running:

```
xcrun simctl erase <UDID>
```

or erase all devices with:

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```